# Assigning to @NSManaged public var locks UI

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I have a Int16 state attribute on my CoreData model which is defined as `@NSManaged public var state: Int16` in the generated file.
I assign to this via an enum's rawValue like so:

```
/// TaskSession.swift
public enum TaskStatus: Int16, CaseIterable {
    case paused 
    case running 
    case complete
    case suspended
}

public var status: TaskStatus {
    get {
        TaskStatus.init(rawValue: self.state) ?? .paused
    }
        
    set(newValue) {
        state = newValue.rawValue
    }
}

func finish() {
    self.status = TaskSessionStatus.complete
}

///Tasks.swift
...
for session in taskSessionsArray where session.status != .complete {
    session.finish()
}
...
```

I've tried assigning to the state attribute directly but the same thing happens - assigning to `state` blocks the UI for a hundred ms or so, which gets worse the larger the collection of tasks becomes.

Comment: Make sure you *only assign* on the UI thread and perform all other tasks in the background.

Comment: "lock UI" - is it a performance slow-down or a deadlock?

Answer (score 0):

Provided code is not testable, but try the following

```
func finish() {
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.status = TaskSessionStatus.complete
  }
}
```